# Excel macro to compare two columns Ax, Bx and when true print Value Cx in different column Dx

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2003, vba

I have an excel report with 60k rows and 30+ columns. I want to compare value `H1` with all the values in column `B:B` and when there is a match, I want to print the value `Nx` to a different column `BF:BF` or `sheet2.A:A`, whichever is simple and then move onto `Hx` and so on.

Please help me out.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Why use macros?

```
[BF2] =IF($H$1=B2; N2; "")
[H2]  =BF2
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will check each cell in column B with the values stored in cell H1 of the same sheet. When the values match it will fill the coresponding cell (by row) in column BF with the column "N" value:
Just fill your sheets names and eventually set a smaller row count (to 10000)

```
Sub CompareValues ()
Dim Wks as Worksheet: Set Wks = Sheets("YourWorkSheetName")
    ' in this worksheet the code will do the lookup and copy values
Dim Wks2 as Worksheet: Set Wks2 = Sheets("YourOtherWorkSheetName")
    ' in this sheet (2) the code will optionally copy the values
CompareValue = Wks.Range("H1").value
    Dim I as integer
    for i = 1 to 10000 ' you can set a smaller value thow
        If Wks.Range("B"&i) = CompareValue then 
        Wks.Range("BF"&i).Value = Wks.Range("N"&i)
        ' to fill the value into another sheet simply replace the Wks with Wks2
        ' Wks2.Range("BF"&i) = = Wks.Range("N"&i)
        end if
    next i
End Sub
```

Hope this helps!